# How to add new line into txt file

Tags: c#, winforms, stream, text-files

I'd like to add new line with text to my date.txt file, but instead of adding it into existing date.txt, app is creating new date.txt file..

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("date.txt");

// write a line of text to the file
tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

// close the stream
tw.Close();
```

I'd like to open txt file, add some text, close it, and later after clicking something: open date.txt, add text, and close it again.

So i can get:

Button pressed: txt opened -> added current time, then close it. Another button pressed, txt opened -> added text "OK", or "NOT OK" in the same line, then close it again.

So my txt file will look like that:

```
2011-11-24 10:00:00 OK
2011-11-25 11:00:00 NOT OK
```

How can i do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 299, accepted):

You could do it easily using

```
File.AppendAllText("date.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

If you need newline

```
File.AppendAllText("date.txt", 
                   DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
```

Anyway if you need your code do this:

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("date.txt", true);
```

with second parameter telling to append to file.
Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) StreamWriter syntax.

Comment: If you're using c# 4 (or newer) compiler, you can put `new StreamWriter("date.txt", append:true)` to make the intention a little clearer.

Answer (score 25):

No new line:

```
File.AppendAllText("file.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

and then to get a new line after OK:

```
File.AppendAllText("file.txt", string.Format("{0}{1}", "OK", Environment.NewLine));
```

Comment: Please use `Environment.Newline` and not `"\r\n"` - not every system agrees on how newlines work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations

Answer (score 14):

Why not do it with one method call:

```
File.AppendAllLines("file.txt", new[] { DateTime.Now.ToString() });
```

which will do the newline for you, and allow you to insert multiple lines at once if you want.

Comment: I prefer this to the accepted answer; you don't need to specify new line

Answer (score 3):

```
var Line = textBox1.Text + "," + textBox2.Text;

File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Documents\m2.txt", Line + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to create and write content to a text file in Unity3D.

```
void CreateLog() {
        string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy_hh-mm-ss");
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("timestamp", timestamp);
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "log_" + timestamp + ".txt";
        // This text is added only once to the file.
        if (!File.Exists(path)) {
            // Create a file to write to.
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + "App initialised");
            }   
        } else {
            // This text is always added, making the file longer over time
            // if it is not deleted.
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path)) {
                sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + "App initialised");
            }   
        }

        // Open the file to read from.
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path)) {
            string line = "";
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Debug.Log(line);
            }
        }
}
```