# using StreamWriter in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, io

I have a console application which writes details of the processed jobs into .txt file. I use this code to do it:

```
StreamWriter jp = new StreamWriter(jobsProcessed);
jp.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
jp.WriteLine(info);
jp.WriteLine("------");
jp.Close();
```

Unfortunately every time a job is being processed new "info" string replaces the previous one. Is there any method to add new text to the end or beginning of the text file?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you wrap the instantiation of the `StreamWriter` in a `using` block.

Comment: Your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255533/how-to-add-new-line-into-txt-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// using (StreamWriter jp = new StreamWriter(jobsProcessed)) Overwrites, not good for you!
using (StreamWriter jp = new StreamWriter(jobsProcessed, true)) // Appends, good for you!
{
    jp.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    jp.WriteLine(info);
    jp.WriteLine("------");
}
```

But you could semplify your code like so:

```
String[] content = File.ReadAllLines(jobsProcessed);

String[] newContent = new String[3];
newContent[0] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
newContent[1] = info;  
newContent[2] = "------";

File.AppendAllLines(jobsProcessed, newContent);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
StreamWriter jp = new StreamWriter(jobsProcessed,true);
```

**Second parameter**

```
//Determines whether data is to be appended to the file. If the file exists
//and append is false, the file is overwritten. If the file exists and append
// is true, the data is appended to the file. Otherwise, a new file is created.
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/clr/thread/17cd8ccf-7e53-41de-b4cc-221da70405a4

Comment: You should explain the code. Code only answers are not always help to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [StreamWriter Constructor (String, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), where second boolean parameter indicates either the data has to be appended to the already available one or not.

And also avoid calling `Close` and use `using` statement

```
using(StreamWriter jp = new StreamWriter(jobsProcessed))
{
    jp.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    jp.WriteLine(info);
    jp.WriteLine("------");
   //jp.Close(); //NO NEED MORE
}
```

The good about this that even if exception occures, which *can* happen, the stream will be `Disposed`, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

There is an overload to the StreamWriter constructor which takes a second parameter called `append`;

```
using (StreamWriter jp = new StreamWriter(jobsProcessed, true))
{
    jp.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    jp.WriteLine(info);
    jp.WriteLine("------");
}
```

It's also better practice to wrap your StreamWriter up in a `using` block like above.

Answer (score 1):

Just amend this:

```
StreamWriter jp = new StreamWriter(jobsProcessed);
```

To this:

```
StreamWriter jp = new StreamWriter(jobsProcessed, true);
```