# How to record and store data when using team foundation explorer?

Tags: c#, tfs, storage

I am working on a C# windows forms project with a friend and we are using TFS for our source control. The program we have written scrapes data off a couple of webpages at regular time intervals and this is updated to the UI.

However, we would like to be able to store this data for future reference. We will be gathering around 1000 bits of data every few seconds for several hours a day.

I'm relatively new to programming and know very little about databases and couldn't find anything on the internet about how to use them with team foundation server. What's the best way to store this data so it is accessible to both me and my colleague?

So far, we've used local XML files but as I say we need somewhere to centrally store the data.

Sorry if there's any information you need that I've missed off - this is the first question I've asked on a forum - but let me know and I'll provide any info I can.

I look forward to your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing specific about TFS that would keep you from using databases.

If you have installed Visual Studio as your IDE to work with TFS as your source control you probably have a copy of SQL Server Express installed.  I would look into how to utilize that.  You may want to look at Linq to SQL or ADO.Net to provide your connectivity to your database from your applcation.  You will likely get a great deal more flexibility and performance depending on how much data you are collecting if you keep it there vs files.

- [ADO.Net Tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet)
- [Linq to SQL Tutorials](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/07/27/links-to-scott-guthrie-s-using-linq-to-sql-tutorials.aspx)
- [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Dan. I opted for a compact sql database in the end and connected via ADO.NET (thanks for the tutorial it was really useful!). This worked reasonably well but had the problem that if we both ran the program separately without checking in in between, we couldn't merge the databases easily. To get around this, I've switched to a MYSql database stored on my rasberry pi acting as a server and connect using ADO.NET. I don't know if that was the best solution but couldn't think of how to merge the local and server copies of the database when checking in on TFS. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to check in the actual databases?  Generally where I have worked developers keep their own local copies of dbs and check in the schema files (tables, store procedures etc).

Answer (score -1):

Create a .txt file  and every time the service runs append a new line to the text file.
[How to add new line into txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255533/how-to-add-new-line-into-txt-file)