# Using Stream to write text

Tags: c#

How do I use the Stream object to write text to a file? It is asking for bytes...

Here is the code:

```
public override void UpdateLog(string emailId)
    {
        using(Stream s = File.OpenWrite(logFile))
            s.Write(emailId);
    }
```

emailId should be written as a line of text in the file.  Also, do I need to include \n to get the text to write as a new line?

Comment: A quick [google](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) search will do the job...

Comment: Look into the `StreamWriter` class

Comment: Or better yet, don't use streams at all if there's no compelling need to stream the data (as there isn't here) and just use the more appropriate `File` methods that do *exactly* what you want.

Comment: Yeah, that directed me to use streamwriter...which worked...but it rewrote the file instead of appending when called.

Comment: You will find a way to easily add a line in a txt file in [this SO post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255533/how-to-add-new-line-into-txt-file

Comment: Ah, so add the second parameter to it.  Trivial, but difficult to find.  Thank you.

Comment: @bordeo It's difficult to find *when you don't look*.  If you had actually looked at the documentation of the type it would have been readily apparent, or searched for that information using a search engine.

Comment: google File append text and you'll get great MSDN articles

Comment: Thanks man, just used the File method in my code.  Coming from Linux where you just pipe your stuff into files, its a little tricky.

Comment: C# is not equivalent of shell scripts, PowerShell (or even just CMD) is close... Obviously you can pipe output to file in Windows too, but to support that you need to read/write to standard input.output (aka Console.Write/Read) - same way as in all *nix systems. Not sure why you think it is trickier.

Comment: Side note: I think your post is not asking about what you want to achieve, but rather what you think you want to do. These are potentially unrelated things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the StreamWriter class like this instead to append:

```
public override void UpdateLog(string emailId)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(path))
    {
        writer.writeLine(emailId);
    }
}
```

Path should be a string path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. And do something similar to the following:

```
using (StreamWriter writer =
        new StreamWriter("somefile.txt", true))
    {
        writer.Write("hello");
        writer.WriteLine("hello again");
        writer.WriteLine("and again");
    }
```

Comment: Will it append to the file instead of overwriting the file when called?

Comment: @bordeo There's an easy way to find out.

Comment: I'm saying that because i was using streamwriter and it was overwriting the file instead of appending. How would I do it with File methods?

Comment: I just revised the answer. Yes it will append if you overload the constructor as I did.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your current code you can extend it like this:

```
public override void UpdateLog(string emailId)
{
    using (Stream s = File.OpenWrite(logFile))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(s))
        {
            writer.Write(emailId);
        }
    }
}
```