# How to write many rows in text file?

Tags: c#

I write/read file text with C#.

My method is:

```
public static void Save(List<DTOSaveFromFile> Items)
{
    File.WriteAllLines(dataPath, (from i in Items select i.Serialize()).ToArray(), Encoding.Default);
}
```

This always overrides data and only insert 1 rows.
How to insert many rows and don't override before rows.

Comment: Can you show some sample input and output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add new line into txt file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255533/how-to-add-new-line-into-txt-file)

Comment: Sample input: user1  sampleemail@gmail.com              16:43

Comment: @fds, I was read your link. I try but it show data in my text file: 
`System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[STU.Email.DTOSaveFromFile,System.Char[]]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Char[]]`
It not add data. Here my code I was edited: http://pastebin.com/K6AYQdw5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`File.AppendAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
public static void Save(List<DTOSaveFromFile> Items)
{
    File.AppendAllLines(dataPath, (from i in Items select i.Serialize()).ToArray(), Encoding.Default);
}
```

From MSDN:

> Appends lines to a file, and then closes the file.

So, this will prevent the file getting overwritten.

Comment: I find don't have any File.AppendAllLines, only have File.AppendAllText. If change to File.AppendAllText it's show error like that `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'`

Comment: I'm using .NET 3.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void Save(List<DTOSaveFromFile> Items)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
    {
        foreach(DTOSaveFromFile d in Items)
            sw.WriteLine(d.Serialize(), Encoding.Default);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, File only contains AppendAllText. Do you use StreamWrite?

Comment: Sorry, I was test your update answer but it have error like:
`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<char>>' to 'string'
`

Comment: 'Try this' answers are discouraged. Your first answer just replaced one word (and that is okay if it fixes the problem). Just explain what you did and where the error was, then future readers can understand what the problem is.